# InfoPath changes the look of the form

Tags: 2013, infopath, bcs

I am following [this guide](http://www.sharepoint911.com/blogs/laura/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=daba3a3b-c338-41d8-bf52-cd897d000cf3&ID=134&Web=dbb90e85-b54c-49f4-8e97-6d8258116ca0) to create a cross site lookup field in SharePoint. I am using SharePoint 2013. The problem is that when I open the form with InfoPath Designer 2013 the form doesn't resemble the style of the existing SharePoint 2013 form at all, how do I get InfoPath to keep the 2013 form style so that when I edit the form it doesn't look different.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can. InfoPath uses its own look and feel, always has. If you want the form to look like out of the box SharePoint, then you will need to manually style it to look that way.

Comment: An alternative solution for modifying the form ordering can be found here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/a4c02c99-3a17-422b-9a88-7303dcc5f8a0/order-of-form-items-in-dispformaspx-and-newformaspx

Comment: And how does that relate to InfoPath?

Comment: It doesn't, but it achieves the same thing I was trying to achieve with InfoPath, without using InfoPath :P I guess my original question should have said, "How do I modify the sharepoint form, I've tried this already in InfoPath, any suggestions?"